# How to implement an SSL certificate on AWS EC2 and ELB with a domain register with Godaddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have inherited a project which is hosted on AWS EC2. The domain is registered with GoDaddy. I am trying to assign an SSL certificate to the application.
The site can be found at: [atlasvehicles.com](http://atlasvehicles.com).

I have done the following things:

1. Created a certificate using AWS Certificate manager and verified it
2. Created an Application load balancer and assigned the SSL certificate. I followed [this document](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/configure-elb-ssl-aws/) up to the end of step 2.
3. I created a new Hosted Zone in Route 53 and added the ip from the EC2 (see pictures below)

[Picture of IP on EC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuOO0.png) | 
[Adding IP to Route 53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J2zt.png)

4. I then went to GoDaddy.com and changed the named server to the one's listed in Route 53.

I now have a situation where it will server up via http but not https. am I bypassing the load balancer with my Route 53 and if so how do I correct this?

Any help on this would be really appreciate.

==========UPDATED==============

Hi I have changed the A record in Route 53 to the alias given in ELB (they're both the same account), but this still doesn't seem to be resolving, and worse, the standard http isn't working now.

Please see the image below for my configuration.

[ELB configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHgvt.png) | [Route 53 config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GAgJ.png)

I appreciate this is probably sensitive information but I'm getting kind of desperate. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://atlas.atlasvehicles.com/ and http://atlas.atlasvehicles.com/ appear to be working now. Did you change anything? You might have just needed to wait for the DNS to propagate. If you still have further issues you will need to include your ALB listener configuration in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are bypassing the load balancer. The load balancer's target should be the EC2 instance. The domain record in Route53 should point to the load balancer (via an Alias record), not the EC2 instance.

Comment: HI Please see the update above, I've changed the A record to an alias in Route 53 but now it wont work at all. Please see updated images in the question

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm still new cloud computing and the one thing I didn't do is wait... properly. Patience it seem is the virtue to ensure it propagates. You were spot on Mark.

Comment: That's not really a cloud computing thing, just DNS in general. Since you switched from using GoDaddy's name servers to Route53 name servers, that needed to propagate throughout all the routers on the Internet, which can typically take about 24 hours.